# Asignar la salida de un comando a una variable

Tags: cmd, batch

En linux seria tan facil como:

```
var = `command $url`
var = $ (command $url)
```

Pero en batch estoy intentando con un for pero no me está llevando el contenido de la variable% URL%:

```
set URL=pagina.com:435435
for /f %%i in ('command  %URL%') do set TITULO=%%i
```

Alguien sabe que pasa

Comment: Pero, ¿estás inicializando la variable URL?

Comment: si usas %%i debes estar usando un archivo .bat o .cmd porque al interno de la shell se usa solo %i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo siguiente funciona en una línea de comandos CMD y cumple con asignar la salida de un comando en una variable.

*shell:*

```
set url=www.google.com
for /f %i in ('curl %url%') do set TITULO=%i
```

*archivo bat o cmd:*

```
set url=www.google.com
for /f %%i in ('curl %url%') do set TITULO=%%i
```

Dado que usas un for puede que haya más de un valor para la variable TITULO, si quieres conservarlos todos en algo parecido a una lista puedes usar lo siguiente:

*archivo bat o cmd:*

```
@echo off

set url=www.google.com

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    for /f %%i in ('curl %url%') do set TITULO=!ListaTitulos! %%i
    
    echo !ListaTitulos!

endlocal

pause
```

Answer (score -1):

Intente este:

```
set URL="http://hola.mundo.com"
for /f %%i in ('command  %URL%') do set TITULO=%%i
```

Comment: no funciona no me coge el valor d ela variable %URL%